# How to use Python Poetry as a "lightweight" virtual environment like `python -m venv <venv>`?

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry

I often prefer `python -m venv <venv>` due to its simplicity and lightweight (no notion of a Poetry "package"), only setting environment variables to direct Python/Pip to use local packages.

How can I use Python Poetry like virtual environments created by `python -m venv <venv>`?

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to use Poetry if `venv` already does what you want. Or I do not understand the question, can you clarify maybe? What is it that you want to achieve but `venv` does not do?

Comment: I want to rely on a single tool, not two :)

Comment: OK. So what is the problem that you have with Poetry? What is it more concretely that you want to do with Poetry but Poetry is not allowing you to do? Do you have a [mre] maybe?

Comment: I want Poetry not to think of the project as a package, that's included (by default) in the virtual environment. I often create a `venv` for the purpose of testing out code in a single `app.py`. With Poetry you're sort of forced to have a folder within the root folder containing the `pyproject.toml` file, with the contents of the package. I really like Poetry, but often don't want all this extra functionality. Does it make sense? :)

Comment: I think I understand. As far as I know (I am not super up-to-date on Poetry's features) it is not possible. Poetry is a development workflow tool. For Poetry: virtual environments are a means to an end. You can not tell Poetry to create a virtual environment directly. You tell Poetry "I want to work on my project with this Python interpreter" (and behind the scenes Poetry creates a virtual environment and does a bunch of other things). I also think Poetry can not work at all if there is no `pyproject.toml` file with Poetry stuff in it.